# How to convert dynamically created JSON object to XML in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How to convert dynamically created JSON object to XML in node.js ?

I have to dynamically create JSON object based on available which contains nested list of objects.

```
var Obj = {
      root: {
        Door_Keeper: {
          ID: {
            '#list': [{
              Key: {
                Name: "Door_Keeper_ID",
                Value: DoorKeeper.dkId
              }
            }, {
              Key: {
                Key_Name: "ID",
                Key_Value: DoorKeeper.id.Id
              }
            }]
          },
          Name: doorKeeper.dkName,
          Description: doorKeeper.dkId,
          Settings: dkSettings,
          '#list':
          //Here I have list of objects which will be added dynamically

        }
      }
    };
```

I want to generate XML string from the above JSON object in node.js

Comment: What do you want this XML to look like? There is no direct correlation between JSON and XML.

Comment: Hi. I am using mongoDB to fetch the data. It gives me list of objects which needs to be converted in tags.

Comment: <root>
 <Door_Keeper>
  <ID>
   <Key>
    <Name>Door_Keeper_ID</Name>
    <Value>rahul</Value>
   </Key>
   <Key>
    <Key_Name>KL12</Key_Name>
    <Key_Value>DEV-KL12</Key_Value>
   </Key>
  </ID>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
  <Description>abc ltd</Description>
  <Settings> xyz </Settings>
  <shits> </shifts>
 </Door_Keeper>
</root>

My result should look like this. In this case for shifts I am getting list of objects which needs to be iterated and converted to XML.

Comment: Have you found the solution? You can try [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the npm library, [js2xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js2xml) and it will be like,

```
var Js2Xml = require("js2xml").Js2Xml;
var obj = ...... //as given by you in the question
var js2xml = new Js2Xml("root", obj);
js2xml.toString();
```

Comment: Hi. I got this but I am stuck at creating this var obj. It contains list of objects. How should I iterate that inside this obj. Once I am able to generate obj then I can pass it to library for conversion.

Comment: For example in ID I have list of keys. I know that its gonna be 2 so I have defined it statically. What If I don't know how many keys will come from DB. How to define it in my var obj .